# how to display images using filename in android

Tags: android, memory, internal

i am using imageAdapter class in which i have an array that stores drawables

```
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                  R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.floral,
                  R.drawable.bluefloral    };
```

in first activity when user click on save button i have saved those images in android internal memory like data/ data/ com.myapp.color , i have get the file name, and file path too and passed it to imageAdapter class  i just wanted to know that through this file name and path how can i save these images in to this array. because through this array i am displaying images in gridview.

Comment: are those images in drawable folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the image inside the **internal or external storage** you can load it by this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If the image inside the **drawable folder** inside the apk you can use:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable_name);
```

If the image inside the **assets folder** you can use:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("image_name.jpg");
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

If the image inside **drawable folder** and you have only the name you can get the resource id by using:

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("image_name_without_extension", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the image id's using their file names. Using this id you can load the image in image view.

If the image name is `my_image` this method would return id value associated with `R.id.my_image`

```
public static int getImageIDFromName(String imageName)
{
    int imageID = 0;
    if(imageName == null
            || imageName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class res = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = res.getField(imageName);
        imageID = field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return imageID;
}
```